# How to update primary key of Entity

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-core

Before you tell me that it is a bad idea to change the primary key of an entity, let me tell you I fully agree...

If I have an entity and try to change the primary key then, YES it is a bad idea for data integrity.

However, suppose you have an entity that is used to join two entities.  Both entities have an Id (primary key).  The entity that you want to change references the primary key of the other two.  I want to change the reference to one of the entities (but it is defined as a primary key).

Example:

```
Class Customer
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name as String
End Class

Class Address
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Description As String
End Class

Class CustomerAddressAssignments
    Public Property CustomerID As Integer
    Public Property Customer As Customer
    Public Property AddressID As Integer
    Public Property Address As Address
End Class
```

Configuration for Customer:
`builder.ToTable("Customers").HasKey(Function(k) k.ID)`
Configuration for Address:
`builder.ToTable("Addresses").HasKey(Function(k) k.ID)`
Configuration for CustomerAddressAssignments:
`builder.ToTable("CustomerAddresses").HasKey(Function(k) New With {k.CustomerID, k.AddressID})`

Now I have loaded a CustomerAddressAssignment and want to change the Customer/Address associated with this assignment.
How should I accomplish this? When I try to save the changes I get: The property 'CustomerAddressAssignment.AddressID' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified.

Comment: Don't change the primary key. It's that simple. If you want a different combination of customer and address then delete the current record and create a new one with the desired combination. If you want to be able to edit an existing record then add another property to act as primary key and place a unique index on the combination of `CustomerID` and `AddressID` instead. You can then change those IDs without changing the primary key.

Comment: That said, it seems like changing the `CustomerID` would be wrong regardless. It also seems like multiple `Customers` for the same `Address` would be wrong too, so this schema just seems wrong. I would suggest that an `Address` should be unique to a `Customer`, even if two `Address` records contain the same data.

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing a primary key; you're changing a foreign key? Your person is "moving house" by you changing which addressid the personid is mapped to, in the middleman table?

Just delete the old mapping and make a new one. Or even better, set the `MovedOutOnDate` property to DateTime.Now, and make a new mapping, and that way you have the person's entire address history maintained for future needs (and the person's current address(es) is defined as the one(s) where the MovedOutOnDate is null

If your mapping table starts storing more information or relating to other tables in and of itself (for example the order history table recording what person and what address was shipped to/billed to) then the table could have it's own single column PK, so that those other tables it relates to don't have a dual column FK